# How to dynamically set a parent table when accessing a collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to fetch data from dynamically different tables depending on which user is logged on and if he is allowed to edit said table, what I thought was going to work was this:

```php
$colaboradores = Colaboradore::where('email', '=', Auth::user()->email)->first();
$tables = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'intervencoes\_%'");
foreach ($tables as $object) {
    $arrays[] = (array)$object;
}
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $string = implode('', $array);
    $test = $colaboradores->Niveis->$string->id;
}
```

And it outputs an error on the last bit of code saying
`"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"`
I have been looking around for hours but couldn't find anything related.
This is all inside a livewire component by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

[dd($colaboradores->Niveis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC0XA.png)

[dd($colaboradores->Niveis->$string)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMlv7.png)

Comment: This error says that this `$colaboradores->Niveis->$string` is not an object, so it could be an array/Collection or even null. Can you `dd($colaboradores->Niveis);` and `dd($colaboradores->Niveis->$string);` and update the question with the results?

Comment: Taking a look at `dd($colaboradores->Niveis->$string)` you can check that it is null. So, if you try to get `$colaboradores->Niveis->$string->id` it is the same that you try to get an attribute from a null variable.
Try to print `dd($string)` and check if it is an attribute of Niveis or if it triggers a relationship on it. Probably it does not, and maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Laerte You were right, the string I was getting was coming in with a typo and when I do `dd($colaboradores->Niveis->$string)` now it comes with a collection. But now whenever I actually try to grab an id, so `dd($colaboradores->Niveis->$string->id)` it says that `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$colaboradores->Niveis->$string` returns a Collection, you need to iterate over it to get results.

```
$test = [];
foreach ($colaboradores->Niveis->$string as $obj) {
    $test[] = $obj->id;
}
```

Then you can check the IDs in `$test` with `dd($test);` for example.

This can cause a problem if `$obj` is not a real object, so you could check it with:

```
if (!is_object($obj)) {
    //Do something - Not an object!
}
```